# SWF file works on Mac browsers but not on PC browsers

Tags: hyperlink, flash

OK this is a new one for me, I have a SWF file where the link only works on Mac browser but does not work on PC browser:

http://luc.edu/wwwtest/studyabroad/

I am using the absolute path for the SWF and check the FLA file and the link is going to the correctly location. Can anyone help me why this is happening? I have also checked my object code and it seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of http://luc.edu/wwwtest/studyabroad/ use http://www.luc.edu/wwwtest/studyabroad/

or instead of :

`<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">`

do

`<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="Always">`